# Setting Variable From inside Firebase Snapshot

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I apologize for my lack of proper terminology, and I'm sure there's a duplicate out there but couldn't find since I didn't know what words to use.  I have a variable that needs to be updated with the snapshot value of the firebase call. But when I `console.log(theNumber)` I'm getting 0.

```
let firebasequery = info.child('todaysTotal')
var totalToday = 0

firebasequery.once('value', snap => {
  let theNumber = snap.val()
  totalToday = theNumber
})

console.log(totalToday)
```

But when I look at the logs:

> 0

Comment: One word: *asynchronous*. You're logging the variable *before* its value has updated.

Comment: @CRice Ah, that would make sense, is this a use case for `async` `await`?

Comment: Could be, if that's what you prefer. Just using promises would suffice as well. I'd say it's up to you as to whether or not to use `async/await` or stick with vanilla promises, since either will get the job done.